# Iterator in ArcGIS Pro looping

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I am trying to migrate my ArcMAP model over to ArcGIS Pro but experiencing some issues. The model is using an iterator to run the model on multiple files. In ArcMap the model would stop once it has gone through all the files in the specified folder, but ArcGIS Pro just keep looping the model indefinitely.

Please advice

Comment: Can you provide more details on what the exact contents are the loop/steps in the model are? A first step could be identifying and verifying whether the properties of each model component are the same when viewing them in ArcGIS Pro. Then you can try exporting it as a python script to see if that approach works or if it reveals inconsistencies between the model in ArcMap. Otherwise, the software/version may be causing this behavior.

Comment: Add you writing the output files to the input folder?